# Variables does not accept more than 3 inputs

Tags: c++

I'm having minor difficulty that infuriates me. Can someone help me out? Both `int boo` (books) and `double pri` (price) doesn't accept more than two inputs. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int id;
    int boo;        //books
    double pri;     //price
    char i;
    
    a:
    cout << "Enter number of books: ";
    cin >> boo;
    cout << "Enter total amount: $";
    cin >> pri;
    boo += boo;
    pri += pri;
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Would you like to purchase more books?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 'y' to continue. Enter 'n' to terminate: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << endl;
    boo += boo;
    pri += pri;
    if (i == 'y' && 'Y')
    {
        goto a;
    }
    else
    {
        CT.Disp();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize for confusing everyone. Everything else is fine, I'm trying to figure out why does the program not accept more than two values when running.
I entered three values. Yet only accepts two:

[image: Console Log]

Comment: What do you mean by "does not accept more than 2 inputs" ?

Comment: Some unrelated comments: don't use goto if you can avoid it, the `&& 'Y'` in your `if` statement does nothing, and feel free to use full variable names instead of three letters.

Comment: When the program loops the book and price variables only adds up to 2 inputs then ignores to rest. I apologize for using 3 letters. kinda lazy to write it all, lol

Comment: For me it is not clear what you are asking. Could you please clarify what your problem is and what inputs lead the the behaviour?

Comment: I guess it is what you want to do: `if (i == 'y' || i== 'Y')`. Besides, a `while` loop would more clear than your `goto`

Comment: I'm guessing `cin >> i` doesn't consume all of your input (e.g. you input `yes` instead of `y`) this causes the next call of `cin >> boo` to fail. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: `boo += boo` is not a problem unless you don't actually want to double the value of `boo`. It is very difficult to see the point of your `+=` operations, in particular the ones where the value is immediately overwritten.

Comment: @Zaiborg I'm not sure about your edit, the code is probably unrelated but as we don't actually know what the problem is it seems premature to remove code that could be hiding some defect that actually causes the problem

Comment: sorry, this description is still too vague. Can you edit your question with the transcript of your interaction? (ie inputs and outputs).

Comment: That code doesn't compile even if you would happen to have the mysterious header.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You may be right, i was assuming that the issue is related to the user input handling.

Comment: @Zaiborg I actually have a header file. I have attached an image about my minor problems.
Thank you!

Comment: When you do that: `cin >> boo;`, you cancel the previously entered numbers. You should use two variables, `boo` and `cumul_boo += boo;`

Comment: As @Damien said, you overwrite your variables with the new input. Introduce sum variables and you example should work as you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another variable. The moment this line happens:

```
cin >> boo;
```

you are wrinting the new value into boo. It does NOT get added to boo. The reason why you think it gets 2 values is because of this:

```
boo += boo;
```

which is effectivly:

```
boo = boo + boo;
```

To fix your code you need anther variable that gets the value from cin and then add it to boo:

```
int bIn;
cin >> bIn;

boo += bIn;
```

Also i suggest you replace the goto with some kind of loop, since goto is considered really bad code design.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Nari there is also something to consider that `>>` ignores EOL , so if you enter two numbers in one line, dividing them by whitespace, `std::cin >> num_books; std::cin >> price; ` would read them both. THis approach to user input is very unstable, and breaks up completely if user inputs nonnumeric string

Answer (score 3):

What you actually mean is: *Why do I only get the result of the last inputs given and why is it 2x of the input given*.

If you would have evaluated with different numbers in each run: (3, 60) (4, 80) (5, 50) you would have gotten (10, 100).

The reason is that you overwrite `boo` and `pri` every time you go through the "loop" and `boo += boo` and `pri += pri` simply doubles the content of the variable as described in the comments to your question.

A general comment also made above: avoid using goto if you can, it is confusing. In this case use a `while-loop` makes way more sense.

Try and look at the program below and how it differs from yours.
It will give you the numbers you expect.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int total_num_books = 0;
    double total_price = 0.0;
    char i = 'y';

    while (i != 'n')
    {
        int num_books;
        double price; 
        std::cout << "Enter number of books: ";
        std::cin >> num_books;
        std::cout << "Enter total amount: $";
        std::cin >> price; 
        
        total_num_books += num_books;
        total_price += price;

        std::cout << "Would you like to purchase more books?" << std::endl
                  << "Enter 'y' to continue. Enter 'n' to terminate: ";
        std::cin >> i;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of books: " << total_num_books
              << " total price: " << total_price << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My only issue was "boo += boo" I replaced it with "totalbooks += books".